# Understanding why this blob of assembly code adds 0x20 and 0x1f

Tags: assembly, memory, delegatecall, memory-pointer

The [execute](https://github.com/dapphub/ds-proxy/blob/e17a2526ad5c9877ba925ff25c1119f519b7369b/src/proxy.sol#L53-L78) function defined in MakerDAO's [DSProxy](https://github.com/dapphub/ds-proxy/blob/e17a2526ad5c9877ba925ff25c1119f519b7369b/src/proxy.sol) contains this blob of assembly code:

```
assembly {
    let succeeded := delegatecall(sub(gas, 5000), _target, add(_data, 0x20), mload(_data), 0, 0)
    let size := returndatasize

    response := mload(0x40)
    mstore(0x40, add(response, and(add(add(size, 0x20), 0x1f), not(0x1f))))
    mstore(response, size)
    returndatacopy(add(response, 0x20), 0, size)

    switch iszero(succeeded)
    case 1 {
        revert(add(response, 0x20), size)
    }
}
```

At a high-level, I understand what this does. It delegate calls to a function on the `_target` contract, in the context of the DSProxy storage. It subtracts 5000 gas from the remaining stipend to ensure that sufficient gas remains for executing the rest of the assembly code. It passes the `_data` (a variable defined as `bytes memory`) as calldata. It then packs the returned value in the `response` variable (defined, again, as `bytes memory`). Finally it checks if the contract call failed, and if it did, it reverts.

It is this line that I struggle to understand:

```
mstore(0x40, add(response, and(add(add(size, 0x20), 0x1f), not(0x1f))))
```

Why did they add `0x20` to `size`, and `0x1f` to the value thereof, and finally AND the negation of `0x1f`? I understand that these are pointers, but I don't know why they are reading from these specific values.

Comment: I might misunderstand, but isn't this adding 2 words (0x20) to the size ptr, then adding 31 bytes (0x1f) then removing 31 bytes (not(0x1f)) ? is this your interpretation too ?  On a further note, I suspect this could be due to solidity internals in that old version; if you check openzeppelin proxy implementation is quite simpler and maybe it can help you delve deeper  https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/proxy/Proxy.sol

Comment: Yes, that's my interpretation as well. The question is *why* they are doing it. I'm looking for an explanation.

Comment: I don't think that this is about an old version of Solidity. If you look at the [docs](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/assembly.html#example) for the v0.8.7 version, it still uses this logic of adding 2 words then adding and removing 31 bytes in an example script.

Comment: I'm debugging it in remix, on a further note, the last operation it's not an ADD, it's an AND; it's surely related to the memory management position related to the returndatasize , it's basically "shift 2 words" from the returndatasize, shift "almost 2 words" from that value (add 0x1f is 31 bytes) and then mask it with not(0x1f) that is "all except last 6 bytes"; could it be to fetch the next function signature ?

Comment: **Update**: I will close this question, because it is a duplicate of [How does this assembly code create a new “memory end”?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/70839/how-does-this-assembly-function-work).

Comment: 0x20 is the first slot of an array, which indicates its length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Info:** 0x40 is a special address:
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/assembly.html#example

> Solidity manages memory in the following way. There is a “free memory pointer” at position 0x40 in memory. If you want to allocate memory, use the memory starting from where this pointer points at and update it.

So the code reads as

```
// how much memory do we need to allocate for the response ?
    let size := returndatasize 

// load the response at the address given by the free memory pointer
    response := mload(0x40)

// save at the free memory pointer address (0x40) the next position of the available memory
    mstore(0x40, add(response, and(add(add(size, 0x20), 0x1f), not(0x1f))))
```

this is to update the free memory pointer (0x40)

**!0x1f is to have the next  position being a multiple of 32:**

- the free memory pointer should point to a rounded position
- the returndata size could not be of a multiple of 32 (for example it could be just 5 bytes)

so this is basically

"set the free memory pointer (0x40) to the next multiple of 32 bytes after the response starting position (response) that i calculate by adding the response size (size)"

Comment: check openzeppelin implementation, I think it's quite easier to read (and wrapped into more advanced functions)